# Drop rows from data frame but skip labels that not contain in the axis

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to drop certain rows based on my given list using pandas, but also to skip those items that do not contain in my data frame.

For example,

```
# My dataframe
id,name
A,Bill
B,Lee
C,Jack

# id list that I want to take out
id,
A,
E, # does not contain in data frame
F, # does not contain in data frame
G, # does not contain in data frame

## I'd like to see in my result...

id,name
B,Lee
C,Jack
```

I have tried `df[~df['id'].isin(given_id_list)]` and `df.set_index('id').drop(given_id_list.set_index('id').index)` but both do not work well.

Any smart suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

this is not the most 'pythonic' solution--but it works. Loop through the indexes, check the ID variable, and drop it if it is in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
#create the sample dataframe
data = {'id':['A','B','C'], 'name': ['jack', 'john', 'bill']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#list of possible rows to drop:
to_drop = ['A', 'F', 'G']

#loop thru each index
for ix in df.index:
    #check if it is a good one to drop
    if df.loc[ix]['id'] in to_drop:
        #drop it if it is
        df.drop(ix, inplace = True)
```